# Unable to publish bundle in CQ5

Tags: osgi, aem

I have created a simple OSGi bundle using the tutorial [given here](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/developing/development_tools/developing_with_crxde.html#Managing%20a%20Bundle). The bundle is working fine in the author instance and is also visible in the felix console ( `http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles` )

However, even after multiple attempts at publishing the bundle, it is still not available in the publish instance. I have tried publishing is in a package and ddirectly in the tree activation page

I had used the below properties to make it work in the author instance:

```
Export-Package: *
Import-Package: *
Private-Package: *
```

Please advice. !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no direct way to publish a bundle from author to publish environment. You will need to upload the JAR file of the bundle in the publish instance felix console  (`http://localhost:4503/system/console/bundles` )

The JAR file will be available in the `/apps/<site-name>/install` directory. 
If you have access, the CQ5 forum had the solution at [this link](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5071606)

Hope it works...

Comment: This doesn't work. The publish instance doesn't have a felix console.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "publishing a bundle".

If you have installed your bundle by copying it to the JCR repository of a CQ5 author system (under /apps/yourapp/install for example), which is the recommended way, you should be able to replicate that install folder to your publish instances so that the bundle gets activated there.

That will of course only work if any dependencies that the bundle requires are available on the publish instances.

Comment: I was not aware of this Install directory and the JAR inside it. so, I took the advice given above and added the JAR to the Felix console on publish environment.

Comment: http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/SlingHowToInstallBundlesViaJCRInstall.html briefly describes how to install bundles via JCR folders, and also how to transfer the results between CQ systems using content packages. Replication would achieve the same results.